# .continueInApp option for IntentResponse is not opening app IOS 12 Beta 6

Tags: swift, beta, ios12, intents-extension

I am handling a custom intent action like this:

```
internal func handle(intent: UsageIntent, completion: @escaping (UsageIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    completion(UsageIntentResponse(code: .continueInApp, userActivity: nil))
}
```

It used to open the app, but now presents a new Siri Screen that says `You'll need to continue in [App]` and gives you a button to open the app.

Is this a new behaviour?? Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour has been reverted in `IOS 12 BETA 9`. Now just navigates to App instead of showing redundant Siri Screen